# MongoDB query returns null even when data exists

Tags: c#, database, mongodb

I've got some class

```
public class User

    {
        [BsonId] //id
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }
        [BsonElement("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; }
        [BsonElement("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; }
        [BsonElement("Email")]
        public string Email { get; }
        [BsonElement("Password")]
        public string Password { get; }
```

And a query to check if user wrote correct password

```
public bool PairEmailAndPass(string email, string password)
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<User>("Users");
            var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq("Email", email);
            var record = collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
            if (record.Password == password) return true;
            else return false;
        }
```

And it always returns false. I made a unit test to see what is the value of **record.Password**, and I noticed, that the query returns an empty object. What's wrong?

That's the function that inserts objects into the database

```
public void AddNewUser(User user)
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<User>("Users");
            collection.InsertOne(user);
        }
```

Comment: Would be great if you can provide the sample data. What if you try to query all and find your desired record is available in the list? Are you connect to the correct database?

Comment: Yes I am connecting to the correct database. If incorrect, MongoDB Compass would create a new one, but it doesn't. If I try to query all, it still returns null.